# How to create a Blob from an URL?

Tags: php, url, blob

I have a URL like that (basic URL) :

`"http://blablablbalbalka.jpg"`

which allows me to retrieve an image on a website.

I would like with PHP, retrieve that image and create a BLOB for an insert in a database.

How can i do that ?

Do I need to use function like file_get_contents ? fopen ?

Thanks :)

Comment: You should try to avoid storing images directly into databases.

Comment: I can't, i use a custom CMS for my job and i can't change that ;)

Comment: yes, file_get_contents does the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use as you say file_get_contents (depending on security on the webserver - see manual for info) or you could use CURL to fetch the image.

```
$img = file_get_contents("theurl");
```

Curl:

```
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "theurl");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
$img = curl_exec($ch);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
```

then insert $img into a BLOB field...